# How to keep home hosted webserver safe

Tags: server

I've got a raspberry pi I used as a web server. It's not for any sort of commercial traffic I just have it as a machine on my network so I can SSH/FTP in.

I recently setup a page linked to a domain which I can browse the contents of my NAS drive which is hosted locally but only accessible externally through the PI where the drive has been virtually mounted.

I was wondering if there was any security flaws and how to prevent them with a web server hosted at my IP.